# Is there a bettery way to work with nested(associated) models in Sails JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I've connected my SailsJs app to a Mongodb database. I'm working on an analytic application. These are the major models in my application:

`User`
`Project`
`Report`
`Event`

A user can have many projects, a project can have many reports and a report can have many events. I have created these relations using `collection` and `model` properties of my models attributes. My problem is why is it so hard to find events of specific user? I wish I could do this:

```
User.
  find({id: id}).
  populate('projects').
  populate('reports').
  populate('events').
  then(function (eventsOfMyUser) {
  });
```

but since only `projects` is an attribute of my `User` model only the first populate works. Shouldn't be an easier way to find a deep model rather than writing nasty and confusing async loops in my controller or model code?

Comment: This is one of those times it makes sense to write your own method function on the model for more complex behaviour. 

Also might be the time to use `.query()` with plain SQL

Comment: @FrederickStark don't you think it's a very simple behavior that waterline fails to handle? I'm starting to think sailsJS really let's you down in these simple situations and I've made a mistake to start using it. I wish I'm wrong or I can fix my issue by making changes in my project. Don't you think it must be a part of framework?

Comment: Yes, it is behaviour that sails / waterline should be able to handle eventually. That's the trouble working with pre-v1.0 frameworks. Would be a good idea to raise an issue on the waterline repo. Or even better, a pull request if you've got the time to make a solution

Answer (score 3):

At the moment sails doesn't have any kind of nested population. The issue to reference: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308

Worth saying there's a pull request to add nested population: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/1052

Pull request isn't merged at the moment but you can use it installing one directly with

```
npm i Atlantis-Software/waterline#deepPopulate
```

With it you can do something like `.populate('projects.reports ...)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is a hook that allows you to do that. It is changing waterline with [Offshore](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/Offshore). Offshore is extended fork of Waterline with deep populate, cache mechanism.

[sails-hook-orm-offshore](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/sails-hook-orm-offshore)

In the road map right now there are:

- Associations Criteria (add default criteria to association)
- Transactions