# Is there any way to populate with associated populate on sails/waterline?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, populate

Is there any way to populate with associated populate on sails/waterline?

Like I have `Product`, `ProductType` and `ProductRule` models.

`Products` has one `ProductType`
`ProductRule` has one `Product`

Now I want something like -

```
ProductRules.find().populate('product'.populate('product_type'))
```

Is there any way? Please help...

Comment: You're asking for deep/nested population. [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations) and [waterline discussion](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/108)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a bettery way to work with nested(associated) models in Sails JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172091/is-there-a-bettery-way-to-work-with-nestedassociated-models-in-sails-js)